# How do I prove $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = log|f(x)|$?

Tags: integration

Assume $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$.
How do I prove that
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = log|f(x)| $$
applies for all continously differentiable functions $f$? Or how do I even get started?

Comment: Hint: let $y=f(x)$

Comment: You are asked to show that $\log|f(x)|$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.  How do you show that something is an *antiderivative* of something else?

Answer (score 1):

One place to start would be to differentiate $\log|f(x)|$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Hint
$$\int\dfrac{df(x)}{f(x)}dx=\ln{|f(x)|}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

set $u=f(x)$ then $du=f'(x)dx$
and thus
$$\int^t\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\int^{f(t)}\frac{1}{u}du=[ln|u|]^{f(t)}=ln|f(t)|+C$$